error filed to open file, permission denied
i try to open users.json file but not in my index.php file
i used requard function your and that the result:

file_get_contents(C:\\XAMPP\\htdocs...): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in...

null
users.php
function getUsers() { 
    $users = json_decode(file_get_contents(\__DIR_\_,'/users.json'),true);
    echo "<pre>";

    var_dump($users);

    echo "</pre>"; } 

index.php
require('users.php');

getUsers();


Between all the obvious weird non-code I spotted something that might help you: change the comma (,) between __DIR__ and '/users.json' into a period (.)
If that doesn't help, reformulate your question correctly.
Remember: the amount of attention you put in formatting and formulating your question  will be equal to the quality of the answers you will get. Use chatGTP if you're not fluent in English to translate for you or to correct you.

there is a problem in your code for path of file you must change Comma to DOT
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents(_DIR_ .'/users.json'),true);

